# Solve least square problem with python cvxpy and constraints

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, cvxpy

I want to solve the  least squares problem with cvxpy in python. For the unconstrained case, everything works just fine:

```
# Import packages.
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# Generate data.
m = 20
n = 15
np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.randn(m, n)
b = np.random.randn(m)

# Define and solve the CVXPY problem.
x = cp.Variable(n)
cost = cp.sum_squares(A @ x - b)
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cost))
prob.solve()

# Print result.
print("\nThe optimal value is", prob.value)
print("The optimal x is")
print(x.value)
print("The norm of the residual is ", cp.norm(A @ x - b, p=2).value)
```

But now I'd like to add additional constraints of the form $x_1=x_2$. I tried the following code

```
# Import packages.
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# Generate data.
m = 20
n = 15
np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.randn(m, n)
b = np.random.randn(m)

# Define and solve the CVXPY problem.
x = cp.Variable(n)
cost = cp.sum_squares(A @ x - b)
constraints = [x[0]==x[1]]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cost), constraints)
prob.solve()

# Print result.
print("\nThe optimal value is", prob.value)
print("The optimal x is")
print(x.value)
print("The norm of the residual is ", cp.norm(A @ x - b, p=2).value)
```

But I always get the following error:
`IndexError: Index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1..`
Can someone please help me? I know one possibility is to set $x_1$ and $x_2$ as single variables, but I this is just a small example for a much bigger problem and it would be a lot of typing for the other one.

Thanks to everyone in advance for their help!

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works great for me. Post full code with everything in order and also post the full output.

Comment: Hello, I edited to post. Hopefully this will clarify my  problem

Comment: Which version of cvxpy? Also, don't be afraid to post the full error with stack trace so one can see line numbers etc. More info is always better and minimizes the number of back and forth rounds of extra questions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure on your side you don't have n=15 but n=1 by some editing accident.

Comment: Yes, that was the error. I did a for-loop over n and clearly for n=1 my code does not make any sense. Thank you!